# How to extract data from certain facebook pages for a specified date range(from and to)?

Tags: java, eclipse, facebook, date, facebook-graph-api

I am stuck up in this date range query. I need to extract data from particular facebook pages for a specified date range.I am able to do this individually, by using since and until fields. But how to use these two fields together.

Here is my code:

```
 public static String getFacebookPostes(Facebook facebook, String searchPost)
            throws FacebookException {
        String searchResult = "Item : " + searchPost + "\n";
        StringBuffer searchMessage = new StringBuffer();
        ResponseList<Post> results = facebook.searchPosts(searchPost, new Reading().since("2014-04-02"));

        String userId="";
        for (Post post : results) {
            System.out.println(post.getMessage());
            searchMessage.append(post.getMessage() + "\n");
            for (int j = 0; j < post.getComments().size(); j++) {
                searchMessage.append(post.getComments().get(j).getFrom()
                        .getName()
                        + ", ");
                searchMessage.append(post.getComments().get(j).getMessage()
                        + ", ");
                searchMessage.append(post.getComments().get(j).getCreatedTime()
                        + ", ");
                searchMessage.append(post.getComments().get(j).getLikeCount()
                        + "\n");
                userId=post.getComments().get(j).getFrom().getId();
                User user = facebook.getUser(userId);
                //System.out.println("ROCK");
                System.out.println(user);
            }
        }
```

Any guidance is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

PS : I am using facebook4j-core-2.0.2.jar and eclipse kepler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://facebook4j.org/en/code-examples.html you can use all date formats descirbed in http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

From my understanding the code would then look like this:

```
ResponseList<Post> results = facebook.searchPosts(searchPost, new Reading().since("2014/04/02").until("2014/04/08"));
```